# How to get Time range in array using android

Tags: android

> I have an array which having time ranges like below,

```
String[] str ={"6.30 AM","6.10 AM","10.00 PM","7.00 PM"};
```

> i want to get the minimum time and maximum time in above array such as "6.10 AM" and "10.00 PM".i can find out using sorting but it takes long time.Is any other method avail.Guide me,Below i sorted like,

```
String[] str ={"1:0 PM","2:0 AM","3:0 PM",.....}; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.getDefault());
Date TimeToCompare = null,Time1 = null;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  TimeToCompare=sdf.parse(str[i]);  
  for(int j=i+1;j<10;j++)
  {
    Time1=sdf.parse(str[j]);
    if(TimeToCompare.after(Time1))
    {
      //sorting
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Iterate over the list saving the min and max. O(n) is the best you're going to get.

Comment: @bstar: can u pls give sample code...

Comment: @sivanesan1 your string's must be in `""`

Comment: Do you have an option on how the time strings are formatted? For instance in 24 hour format so you'd have "0630", "0610", "2200", "1900". If you could do that then you could just use a sorted collection of some sort and get the first and last elements from the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution makes one pass through the array, keeping track of the min and max times.  Runs in O(n).

```
double maxTime = 0.0;
double minTime = 0.0;
for(String s : str) {
    String[] parts = str.split(" ");
    double time = Double.parse(parts[0]);
    if (parts[1].equals("PM")) {
        time += 12;
    }

    if (time > maxTime) {
        maxTime = time;
    }

    if (time < minTime) {
        minTime = time;
    }
}

// convert doubles back into strings and print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Date-Time Values

When working with date-time values, it's usually best to work with them *as* date-time values.

Parse the strings as date-time values, collect them, sort the collection, and retrieve the first and last elements in collection to get earliest & latest values. Convert back to strings if needed.

## Joda-Time & java.time

You can easily parse the strings to create date-time objects.

However avoid using the bundled java.util.Date & .Calendar classes in Java as they are notoriously troublesome. Furthermore, they always combine date and time-of-day while in your case you have only a time-of-day.

Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html) or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8. Both offer a day-of-time only class, [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html).

## Example Code

Example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

Convert your array to Collection as I prefer to not work with arrays.

```
String[] strings = { "6.30 AM", "6.10 AM", "10.00 PM", "7.00 PM" };
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList( strings );
```

Create an empty collection to collect our LocalTime objects as we instantiate them.

```
List<LocalTime> localTimes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create a formatter to parse your particular string format. By the way, if you can change the source of these strings, I suggest creating strings in 24-hour format without the "AM/PM", akin to the standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "h'.'mm aa" );
```

Loop through our collection of strings, parsing each one. Store the new `LocalTime` instance in a collection.

```
for ( String string : stringList ) {
    LocalTime localTime = formatter.parseLocalTime( string );
    localTimes.add( localTime );
}
```

Sort the collection of `LocalTime` objects, to determine the earliest and latest.

```
Collections.sort( localTimes ); // Ascending order. Earliest first, latest last.
```

Retrieve the earliest and latest.

```
LocalTime earliest = localTimes.get( 0 );
LocalTime latest = localTimes.get( localTimes.size() - 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "localTimes: " + localTimes );
if ( !( localTimes.isEmpty() ) ) {
    System.out.println( "earliest: " + formatter.print( earliest ) );
    System.out.println( "latest: " + formatter.print( latest ) );
}
```

When run…

```
localTimes: [06:10:00.000, 06:30:00.000, 19:00:00.000, 22:00:00.000]
earliest: 6.10 AM
latest: 10.00 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample solution picked from ggreiner @

[How to sort a list of time strings in Java or Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976063/how-to-sort-a-list-of-time-strings-in-java-or-groovy)

```
 String[] str ={"6.30 AM","6.10 AM","10.00 PM","7.00 PM"};
 List<String> times = Arrays.asList(str); // convert int to list
 Collections.sort(times, new MyComparator()); // use a custom comparator
 Log.i("Min time is ",""+times.get(0));
 Log.i("Max Time is ",""+times.get(times.size()-1));
```

Custom Comparator

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>
{

    private DateFormat primaryFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h.mm a");

    @Override
       public int compare(String time1, String time2){
           return timeInMillis(time1) - timeInMillis(time2); 
       }

       public int timeInMillis(String time){
           return timeInMillis(time, primaryFormat);
       }

            // in milliseconds
    private int timeInMillis(String time, DateFormat format) {

        Date date = null ;

         try {
            date  = format.parse(time); // 
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


       return (int)date.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: High chances of a `NullPointerException` in last statement.

Comment: @sd yes you can put a null check and return appropriate value

Comment: O(nlogn) average case

Comment: @bstar55 could be i din't check that

Comment: @bstar55 yes its nlog(n) time complexity http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

 String[] str =new String[]{"6.30 AM","6.10 AM","10.00 PM","7.00 PM"};

 ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
 HashMap<Double,String> map = new HashMap<Double, String>();
 for (int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
      list.add(Double.parseDouble(str[i].split(" ")[0]));
      map.put(Double.parseDouble(str[i].split(" ")[0]),str[i]);
 }
 System.out.println("Min >> " +map.get(Collections.min(list)));
 System.out.println("Max >> "+map.get(Collections.max(list)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use these, But you may need some pre-arragments

```
Collections.max(arrayList);

Collections.min(arrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're originally filling the array of values, like are you getting the long from the system then you could compare those. Or create an class that holds the value part and the AM or PM seperately like a flag or something, so then sort between AM and PM then values. I dabbled a lot with java date and calendars, and just use JodaTime. It's convenient!